# $\int \dfrac {xe^{2x}}{1+2x^2}~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Working on integration by parts problem set. Stuck with this problem.

> $\int \dfrac {xe^{2x}}{1+2x^2}~dx$
>   Tried the following:
>
> Let $u=e^{2x}$, therefore $du=2e^{2x}~dx$
>
> $dv=\dfrac {x}{1+2x^2}~dx$, therefore $v=\dfrac {ln|1+2x^2|}{4}$

By integration by parts:

> $\int \dfrac {xe^{2x}}{1+2x^2}~dx=\dfrac {e^{2x}ln|1+2x^2|}{4}-\int \dfrac {2e^{2x}ln|1+2x^2|}{4}$

I did a second integration by parts on the integral above, and it all went so messy. Anybody help?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a nice answer, since [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+xe^%282x%29+%2F+%281+%2B+2x^2%29) gives an answer involving the exponential integral.